# How to include DropdownList chosen item id value into Api function to extract another table from DB using Axios in React?

Tags: reactjs, database, axios, material-ui

I am new to React, so sorry for messing questions.

I have React with Material UI, Express, MySQL app and dropdown menu where I extract data from table "diseases" from my database that is nicely displayed.
Now I need to extract data from table "procedures" which depends on what choice has been made by user in dropdown list. There can be several procedures that are good for several diseases and back so I created intermediate entity that consists of id's.

Now if I press button "Search" and watch the problem in inspect it throws:

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `DropDiseases`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information. I read the link, but I'm not sure how do I realise it. Appreciate any help!

````
//  TODO Extract list of diseases from db into dropdown list
function DropDiseases() {
  const [diseases, setDiseases] = useState([]);

  const loadData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/diseases/all/et");
    setDiseases(response.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);
  console.log(diseases);

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // TODO Extract data from DB depending on selected value in Dropdown
  const [procedures, setProcedures] = useState([]);

  const loadProcedures = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:4000/procedures/procedures_diseases"
    );
    setProcedures(result.data);
  };

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={5}>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        {/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */}
        {/* Dropdown element */}
        <Autocomplete
          multiple
          id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
          options={diseases}
          disableCloseOnSelect
          getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.dis_title_et}`}
          renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
            <li {...props}>
              <Checkbox
                icon={icon}
                checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                checked={selected}
              />
              {[option.dis_title_et]}
            </li>
          )}
          style={{ width: 500 }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField {...params} label="Haigused" placeholder="Favorites" />
          )}
        />
      </Grid>

      {/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */}
      {/* Fetching Procedures data from DataBase */}

      <Grid style={classes.extractData} item xs={6}>
        <Button spacing={5} onClick={loadProcedures} variant="contained">
          Search
        </Button>

        {procedures.map((val, key) => {
          return (
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Typography variant="h6">
                Procedure{procedures.proc_title_et}
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="body1">body1 </Typography>
            </Grid>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
export default DropDiseases;
```

On Sever there is structure conrollers, models and routes files
in Models I make such query
```
  static findAllProceduresOnDiseases() {
    let sql = `Select proc_title_et, proc_descr_et, proc_duration, proc_price FROM procedures 
    INNER JOIN procedures_diseases ON procedures.id=procedures_diseases.procedures_id 
    INNER JOIN diseases ON procedures_diseases.diseases_id=diseases.id;`;
    return db.execute(sql);
  }
````

Should I include in SQL clause after all Inner Joins WHERE ( to include diseases.id=${diseases.id} and in controller for "disease" id that catches from dropdown list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Comment: Not exactly, as i don't undestand how to include disease id into search into this funciton:

const loadProcedures = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:4000/procedures/procedures_diseases"
    );
    setProcedures(result.data);
  };

by the way its done with class component and I use functional.

Comment: How is that related to the error you're describing in the question?  Please note that the goal of a Stack Overflow question is to solve a specific problem, not to be used as a general tutoring service to build your entire application.  If you have a separate question, please ask it separately.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Im just Asking how can I include id of one table into Api function

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify what you are asking.  Currently the question focuses primarily on a specific error message, which is unrelated to what you are now describing and which is answered thoroughly by the proposed duplicate.  If you're trying to ask something else, describe what you are trying to ask.  What is the specific problem you have encountered?  Are you asking how to include a value in your URL string?  How to pass a value to that function?  Something else?  What specifically have you attempted and how specifically does it not work as expected?

Comment: thnks for help!

Comment: I have updated the question. I am really new to react. i made some courses, but there weren't any close examplese..only very simple API's like how to extract the same dropdown list from db, or catch the state onChange

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by this map method here:

```
{procedures.map((val, key) => {
    return (
        <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Typography variant="h6">
                Procedure{procedures.proc_title_et}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body1">body1 </Typography>
        </Grid>
    );
})}
```

For each grid item you output, it must have a key property where the value is unique. If you can add a unique id in your SQL query to use, then great!

Keys are required on your looped items so react can tell the difference between each one. For example, if each row was a component, each could have its own state/props etc, so having a unique keys prevents issues.

So once you have your ID (you could use key, but it's generally frowned upon?) it's just:

```
<Grid item xs={6} key={THE_UNIQUE_ITEM_ID_HERE}>
```

And that will fix the issue.